# for ssh without password, are both ways correct

Tags: linux, ssh

Now I need to ssh to a Linux Machine B from another Linux or Mac or Windows with Putty (Machine A). I've seen two ways to do that.

1. Generate public and private key on Machine A. Send the public key to Machine B and add it to authorized keys file. And now Machine A can ssh to Machine B without any password.
2. Generate public and private key on Machine B. Send the private key to Machine A. And now Machine A can ssh to Machine B with B's private key.

So are both ways correct? What are the differences? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method 1.

Private keys are intended to be just that -- private.  No other machine, person, or account should ever see another's private key.  Method 2, while it may work, is, no offense meant, kind of a nasty hack that defeats the purpose of having keys in the first place.

Comment: Hi Jon, then why for AWS, it gives you a key (private key?) in order to connect to their server?

Comment: Hm.. I'm not familiar with AWS' methodology, so this is a guess, but I suspect that gives you what it calls the private key so that, so long as it remains private, only you can connect.  Keys come in pairs, and they keep the matching one to confirm your identity when connecting.  "Public" and "private" aren't inherent properties -- they're just label indicating which key was chosen to fill which role.  They're really just numbers that are used to match up with each other.

Comment: I don't feel like I answered what you were asking -- Amazon generates they keys for you, so they do have your private key before they give it to you, but the only thing it matches is the key they keep to confirm your identity, so it seems okay.  I guess true paranoia would urge you to generate your own keys so that no one else, even what you're connecting to, ever has both.  The idea here is that, if you give that key to anyone *else*, then they can impersonate you to Amazon.

Comment: Also, in the original scenario of the question, in case 2., it may be that doing it that way just reverses the public/private roles of the keys.  "Public" and "private" aren't inherent properties of anything -- they're just labels to keep track of the roles each key was chosen to fulfill.  I didn't mean to sound too harsh up there -- it's just that the examples given to explain how this all works often depict scenarios on the level of life-and-death, national security.  So the best practices tend to be stated with a certain.. intensity.  :)

Comment: Here is a paragraph that I got from Amazon: "A key pair consists of a public key that AWS stores, and a private key file that you store. Together, they allow you to connect to your instance securely. For Windows AMIs, the private key file is required to obtain the password used to log into your instance. For Linux AMIs, the private key file allows you to securely SSH into your instance." So it looks like we are using the **private key** to SSH into the AWS instance.